# If I install a non-OEM windows, will boot logo change?

Tags: windows, boot

I have an MSI and it has pre-installed windows 8 in it. If I buy windows 8.1 pro and install it via DVD, will it change my boot logo animation?

Comment: Why are you going to buy a version of Windows that is 100% free ( as in air ) for `Windows 8` users?

Comment: You also don't need to purchase `Windows 8.1` if you want an .ISO to install it.

Comment: Actually you may. The poster mentions buying 8.1 pro but does not state that the laptop comes with pro. If it only has 8 rather than 8 pro he does need to buy.

Comment: @Ramhound : Almsgiving.  Or, if you prefer: altruism, philanthropy, charity, humanitarianism, public-spiritedness, social conscience.  Gotta help them poor folk.

Comment: @birdman3131 - If we go down that route the question isn't clear and thus should be clarified.

Comment: @TOOGAM - What?  Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, the logo is stored in the UEFI and doesn't change if you reinstall Windows 8. [Windows 8 will use this OEM logo during boot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/20/reengineering-the-windows-boot-experience.aspx).

[image]

It only changes to the generic Windows logo if you change the boot mode to legacy or disable the UEFI Graphics protocol (GOP), like I did on my Dell Laptop, to be able to boot Windows 7 in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 2):

On some UEFI systems, there's a vendor-specific logo, which is stored on the UEFI firmware in an ACPI table called Boot Graphics Resource Table (BGRT). If your current MSI logo is stored there, then it will not change by simple reinstallation.

If the BGRT does not exist, Windows uses the logo stored in bootres.dll, just as with legacy BIOS. It's in theory possible that the MSI logo is embedded here.

However, there are ways to change the logo.

### UEFI and BGRT

It is possible to create an EFI application which temporarily modifies the ACPI tables (including BGRT) and then proceeds to load the actual Windows boot manager. This application must then be booted instead of the original Windows boot manager (bootmgfw.efi). BGRT uses the common BMP image format (Windows 3.x BMP, or BMP3) with 24-bit or 32-bit colors.

I've created [HackBGRT](https://metabolix.dy.fi/ohjelmointi/esimerkit/HackBGRT/), which is a simple EFI application for the purpose. HackBGRT reads its configuration file, loads the specified BMP to BGRT, sets the coordinates appropriately and loads another EFI application (usually the Windows boot manager, bootmgfw.efi).

I'm not aware of any other tools for specifically modifying BGRT, although the Clover EFI bootloader has support for at least many other kinds of ACPI table modification. This is why I created my own.

This method applies to any UEFI-based systems with BGRT support, at least in theory.

Some motherboards may also have specific tools for changing the boot logo; at least Intel has released such tools. Most do not.

### BIOS or UEFI without BGRT

If BGRT is not used, the Windows logo may be replaced by modifying a file named bootres.dll with a tool such as [8oot Logo Changer](http://codigobit.net/app/2). As this is a signed file, Windows must be set to testsigning mode with the mentioned tool (or by executing `Bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON`). On UEFI systems the bootres.dll file is on the EFI system partition, whereas on BIOS systems it's in the Windows installation directory.

Comment: Please note that disclosure of your affiliation is required, and that even promoting free software might be considered spamming if all your posts mention it.

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the comment, I've disclosed my affiliation. However, I'm not exactly promoting my (free) software; instead, I've created it because I had this same need and I couldn't find anything ready. It's a valid (and currently the only valid?) solution for changing the logo, so regarding it as spam wouldn't be very wise.

Comment: You don't have to find every single question and post exact same answer.  A single answer is enough, and I see three identical answers advertising the same program honestly, as spam.

Comment: @Ramhound I can see your point. Maybe someone should mark the questions as duplicates, then. (I can't do that, clearly.) Also, feel free to provide an alternative solution or program, if you know of one. I used a couple of nights on the subject and couldn't find any.

Comment: @Metabolix - You certainly could flag the questions as duplicates if you wanted too.

Comment: @metabolix, thanks. This is the most complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of the boot animation. One part is the logo that has been defined in the UEFI firmware, and one part that is included in your shipped Windows installation where the loading rings starts spinning.

The UEFI firmware logo is hard to edit, so that will stay the same for an OS reinstall.

The Windows boot logo is stored with your current Windows installation however, so it will be reverted to the logo shipped with that installation medium.

If you would like to restore the Windows boot logo, you might want to make a backup of `C:\Windows\Boot\Resources\bootres.dll` and restore it with your new installation.

Comment: no, the logo is stored in the UEFI and doesn't change

Comment: @magicandre1981 Depends on what part of the boot logo you mean, there is one part UEFI boot, and a part Windows boot. Both have their own resource.

Comment: no, in UEFI boot, Windows uses the OEM logo: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/20/reengineering-the-windows-boot-experience.aspx